# IIS FTP not denying access to disabled users

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

I'm running FTP under IIS on a windows 2008 server. The computer is not part of a domain. I'm also using User Isolation.

I setup a test user to verify that I had connectivity to the server from the Internet. I used an online FTP client to test connectivity. I logged into the server successfully. Once I was done with my test, I disabled the user account in "Computer Manager". After I disabled the account I attempted to connect again from the online FTP client. To my surprise, it let me login to the server with the disabled account. My first thought was the online tool must be caching the results. To test this theory I renamed one of the files in the user's home folder and connected again. Sure enough, the online client connected successfully again and retrieved an updated file list with the most recent file names.

This seems like a pretty bad security flaw in windows 2008. What's going on here? Is the FTP service caching the user database and therefore authenticating against stale data?

Eventually it will deny the user but it will take about a 1/2 hour for the system to recognize that the user is disabled.

EDIT:

I used the following test sites to verify that I could logon to my ftp site as a disabled user
https://ftptest.net/
https://www.infobyip.com/ftptest.php

Here are some of the IIS settings for this site:

- Anonymous Authentication is Disabled
- Basic Authentication is Enabled
- FTP Directory Browsing = MS-DOS
- Allow SSL Connections is checked
- Ftp logging is set to rollover log files Daily
- FTP User Isolation is set to User Name Directory (disable global virtual Directories)

Comment: `This seems like a pretty bad security flaw in windows 2008.` - My guess is this is a configuration problem, not a "flaw" in Windows Server 2008. Maybe not cast aspersions until you actually find the cause of the issue?

Comment: If you could point me in the direction of the configuration setting called "letDisabledUsersLogon" so I can fix this, I'll gladly absolve Microsoft of blame

Comment: Can you provide us with the configuration settings so as to asses them as well as the URL to the testing site so as to assess it?

Comment: I've updated my post to include the test sites

Comment: I do not feel comfortable posting the host name of the server that is exhibiting these issues. I've updated my post the reflect the fact that eventually it will recognize disabled users, it just takes about a 1/2 hour.

Comment: We don't need to know specifics about the identity your server, just specifics about the actual configuration settings of FTP on the server.

Comment: I've updated my post to include the settings defined under IIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS uses a Token that would need to be removed from the cache to prevent a person that has previously been able to access the site. The minimum interval that can be set to clear this cache is 15 minutes. If you restart IIS the cache is also cleared.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/152526/changing-the-default-interval-for-user-tokens-in-iis